# Setting ui-router states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I started using ui-router, and still can't get my head around it. I think I've figured how to set states for simple cases, yet can't figure how to do this.

what I need is to have state(s) that manage urls like `#/tables/table1`, `#/tables/table2`, `#/tables/table3` etc.

I figured this:

```
<ui-view="container"/>

$stateProvider
.state 'tables',
    url: '/tables/:table'
    views: 'container':
        templateUrl: 'views/table-view.html'
        controller: 'tableCtrl'
```

So this kinda works, but what I need now is instead of reloading controller and the view everytime when url changes, I want to keep same controller, same view, yet to detect state changes. So the first time it hits the state - load the controller, next time the state changes - keep the same controller, same view, and detect in controller new route params. How do I do that?

Comment: "I want to keep same controller, same view, yet to detect state changes." - please explain this in your question

Comment: You can specify the same controller and view for different states.

Answer (score 0):

Use listen for $onStateChange in your controller

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
   if (toState === fromState && toState.name === "container") {
      event.preventDefault();
      // get the params from the toParams that you want. 
   }
})
```